# Lint rule for no-restricted-properties nested object

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

I would like to create a lint rule to block the usage of window.location.href but allow using any other window.location properties.

This one is working for all location sub methods:

```
"no-restricted-properties": \["error", {
"object": "window",
"property": "location",
}\]
```

But I would like to block only the href method.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i got it:
"no-restricted-properties": ["error", { "object": ['window']['location'], "property": "href", }]

Comment: This doesn't work however [no-restricted-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75974135/3784008) does work.