# Eslint disallow usage of specific env variable

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I have a super secret variable `SUPERBASE_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ROLE` which I don't want my devs to use anywhere except for specific location.

I am trying to use this rule:

```
"no-restricted-properties": [
      "error",
      {
        "object": "process",
        "property": "env.SUPERBASE_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ROLE",
        "message": "Usage of process.env.SUPERBASE_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ROLE is not allowed."
      }
    ]
```

But this fails, can someone tell me what is going wrong or what is the way to restrict the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) instead:

```json
"rules": {
  "no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
    "MemberExpression[type=MemberExpression][object.type=MemberExpression][object.object.type=Identifier][object.object.name=process][object.property.type=Identifier][object.property.name=env][property.type=Identifier][property.name=SUPERBASE_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ROLE]"
  ],
}
```

You can evaluate the AST to reproduce rules like this using [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). There are also similar examples at https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8505.